# CSS Move Animation not working in FF or IE, I have all the vendor prefixes and have researched for days

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I have been researching this for days on Google and stackoverflow. Nothing seems to help and I believe I have every vendor prefix necessary as well as all of the correct code. I have even had other developers look at this for me and they believed it looked correct. I am attempting a Move Animation for a text scroll using CSS Animation. I'm not sure if I am missing something obvious, have a typo or if it is just not possible to get this to work on FF and IE. It works fine on Chrome and in Safari. Please go easy on me, I am pretty new at this and this is my first SO question. I have seriously spent at least 6-8 hours researching and attempting to figure out what I am doing wrong with no luck. I was able to make some tweaks that were recommended, but nothing made it work for me in FF or IE.

Here is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite">

<div class="text-scroll">
  <p>I'm a</p>
  <div class="scrolling-words">
    <p>front end engineer.</p>
    <p>curious creator.</p>
    <p>knowledge junkie.</p>
    <p>collaborator.</p>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/notebook.png');
}

* {
font-family: "Special Elite", cursive;
}

/*******************************
ROLLING TEXT KEYFRAME
********************************/

.text-scroll p {
height: 20px;
float: left;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
font-size: 43px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 22%;
}

.text-scroll {
max-height: 50px;
max-width: 586px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 15%;
float: left;
}

.scrolling-words {
overflow: hidden;
height: 54px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-top: 21%;
}

.scrolling-words p {
margin: 0 0 30px;
padding-top: 5px;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-animation: move 8s 1s infinite;
-moz-animation: move 8s 1s infinite;
-o-animation: move 8s 1s infinite;
animation: move 8s 1s infinite;
font-size: 43px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
0%  { top:  0px;   }
20% { top: -56px;  }
40% { top: -110px; }
60% { top: -167px; }
80% { top: -175px; }
80% { top: -0px;   }
}

@-o-keyframes move {
0%  { top:  0px;   }
20% { top: -56px;  }
40% { top: -110px; }
60% { top: -167px; }
80% { top: -175px; }
80% { top: -0px;   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
0%  { top:  0px;   }
20% { top: -56px;  }
40% { top: -110px; }
60% { top: -167px; }
80% { top: -175px; }
80% { top: -0px;   }
}

@keyframes move {
0%  { top:  0px;   }
20% { top: -56px;  }
40% { top: -110px; }
60% { top: -167px; }
80% { top: -175px; }
80% { top: -0px;   }
}
/*******************************/
```

Thank you to anyone who helps. I have my code available in CodePen as well, here: http://codepen.io/raveve/pen/NPmPRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the second `80%` by `100%` works for me :

```
  @keyframes move {
    0%  { top:  0px;   }
    20% { top: -56px;  }
    40% { top: -110px; }
    60% { top: -167px; }
    80% { top: -175px; }
    100% { top: -0px;   }
  }
```

Anyways you don't need specific browser properties. All recent browsers support CSS transitions.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! I cannot believe it was something that simple. I have spent so much time on this. I really appreciate the help!